# Using ImageMagick in C#/VB To Center Annotate Horizontally but Set Position Vertically

Tags: c#, vb.net, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick to add text to an image and I need that text to be centered horizontally but I also want to be able to set the vertical position.  My code that works but places the text 50 pixels from the left of the canvas edge is:

```
        'This adds the address text block
        image.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Transparent
        image.Settings.StrokeColor = MagickColors.Transparent
        image.Settings.FontPointsize = 195
        image.Annotate("508 West Earl Street", New MagickGeometry(50, 300, 150, 75), Gravity.Undefined, 0)
```

I need the code to center it horizontally and make it 300px from the top vertically; something like below but I can't figure out what to put in place of the X coordinate to center it.

```
        'This adds the address text block and should center it.
        image.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Transparent
        image.Settings.StrokeColor = MagickColors.Transparent
        image.Settings.FontPointsize = 195
        image.Annotate("508 West Earl Street", New MagickGeometry('This Value Needs to Center it', 300, 150, 75), Gravity.Undefined, 0)
```

Comment: Use -gravity north and then use the equivalent of -annotate "some text" +0+300. That will start the text horizontally centered, but move it down 300 pixels from the top (north).

Comment: I guess the problem is going to be to figure out what the equivalent is in C#/VB.  Below is what I have tried and the "Gravity.North has no effect; the text is always on the left side of the canvas.  image.Annotate("Test", New MagickGeometry(0, 300, 150, 75), Gravity.North, 0)  I have also tried image.Annotate("Test", Gravity.North, New MagickGeometry(0, 300, 150, 75), 0) with the same result.

Comment: I do not understand why you need 4 values, just to put the image down 300 in Y, if you use gravity north. Try setting them to 0, so you have (0,300,0,0).

Comment: image.Annotate("Test", New MagickGeometry(0, 365, 0, 0), Gravity.North, 0) doesn't work either.  It places the text with most of it off of the left hand side of the canvas.

Comment: What do the 4 numbers mean in the arguments? Are they offsets or sizes or rotation angles? Can you point me to the documentation? Otherwise, I suggest you post your question to dlemstra, the developer of Magick.NET at either https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET or https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27

Comment: The four numbers are (x, y, width, height).  Width and height actually make no difference here because the text is at the top left of the container.  They could be 0, 0.  I figured that out from examples and experimentation.  The documentation that I have found for C# is real sparse so I can't really point you to it.  Most of the documentation is for the command line version but there are some examples posted at https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/ImageMagick/MagickImage/Annotate/php-magickimage-annotate-method-examples.html.

Comment: If the code requires the rectangular limits (x,y,w,h) of the text, then you likely will have to compute the offsets from the top left corner of the image to the needed top left corner of the rectangle in order to center it the way you want. Given the x,y,w,h you can compute the center of the rectangle and x,y offset between the center and its top left corner. Given the location you want for the center of the rectangle, you can then subtract the x and y distances from the top left corner of the rectangle from this location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the width of your image, divide that in half. You can also set the `gravity` property to `center` to center align your text. Your annotation code should look something like the following:

```
image.Annotate("508 West Earl Street", New MagickGeometry(image.width/2, 300, 150, 75), Gravity.Center, 0)
```

[Source](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/)

Comment: One needs to set `gravity` to `north` as I said in my comment and then use a +300 Y offset so that the text is horizontally centered and down 300 px from the top.

Comment: Your solution works with one alteration.  I could not access image.width from within MagikGeometry so I placed it into a variable and then used the variable in MagikGeometry like this:  Dim width As Integer = image.Width
   Dim widthhalf As Integer = widthe / 2
   image.Annotate("508 West Earl Street", New MagickGeometry(widthhalf, 300, 150, 75), Gravity.Center, 0)  Thank you!